# Quotes override list item numbers

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, markdown

Possible bug.  Numbers after quote markdown get overridden

Example (edit to see the problem):

> 1. This is my first **very** important point

This is a very interesting point

> 2. This is my second **very** important point

I do declare, sir, this looks similar to your first point.

Comment: numbered lists always start at 1, no matter what number you type in. When you interrupt the list it creates a new list

Comment: But this isn't a markdown list, it's a quote `>`, are they treated the same?

Comment: When you write `1. `, markdown parses it as the start of a numbered list

Comment: Why would it not be a new list after each new paragraph? You should mention in what cases you're doing this and what you're expecting.

Comment: @random - If you're quoting someone else's list

Comment: @dfb It's a valid use case, but not really important enough (and not a bug, it's by design, Markdown can't render _everything_). Use one of the hacks.

Comment: @YannisRizos - Sure, just checking, thanks for the hacks

Comment: [status-lists-in-markdown-suck-and-we-arent-messing-with-it]

Comment: This is very inconvenient when quoting large sections from a standard etc. Unless you are aware of the bug/"feature", SO will mess up your whole post. Why spend time implementing "features" that are completely useless?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
> 1\. This is my first **very** important point

This is a very interesting point

> 2\. This is my second **very** important point

etc.
```

> 1. This is my first **very** important point

This is a very interesting point

> 2. This is my second **very** important point

etc.

Comment: Less typing [than my hack](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/143257/162704) but the backticks change the font.

Comment: I personally prefer `1\.` and `2\.` as it doesn't improperly format the numbers as inline code blocks.

Comment: @animuson agreed that's a better solution... updated

Answer (score 4):

> 1. This is my first **very** important point

This is a very interesting point

> 2. This is my second **very** important point

I do declare, sir, this is also a very interesting point!

---

The simple hack:

```
> <!---->1. This is my first **very** important point

This is a very interesting point

> <!---->2. This is my second **very** important point

I do declare, sir, this is also a very interesting point!
```

Comment: I'll just note that this is not actually parsed as a markdown list; it just looks like one

Comment: @murgatroid99 Obviously it's just a workaround ;)

Comment: I just wanted to make sure other people reading it would realize without looking at the edits

Comment: @murgatroid99 I've updated the answer to clearly show it's a hack.